# How to refuse a websocket handshake in a tornado websocket handler

Tags: python, websocket, tornado, handshake

So I'm doing a unittest of a tornado server I programmed which has a `websocketHandler`. This is my testing code:

```
def test_unauthorized_websocket(self):
    message = "Hey bro"     
    ws = websocket.create_connection('ws://localhost:8888/ws', header=['Authorization: false'])
    send_dict = {'command': test_command, 'message': message}
    serialized_dict = json.dumps(send_dict)
    ws.send(serialized_dict)
    response = ws.recv()
    #test response with assert
```

My goal with this test was to prove that my tornado server correctly refuses and closes this websocket connection because of wrong authentication header.
This is my tornado `websocketHandler` code:

```
class WebSocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):

   def open(self):
      #some code
      headers = self.request.headers
      try:
          auth = headers['Authorization']
      except KeyError:
          self.close(code = 1002, reason = "Unauthorized websocket")
          print("IT'S CLOSED")
          return

       if auth == "true":
          print("Authorized Websocket!")
          #some code
       else:
          print("Unauthorized Websocket... :-(")
          self.close(code = 1002, reason = "Unauthorized websocket")
```

So when the authentication is wrong, `self.close()` is called (not sure I need code and reason). This should close the websocket. But this doesn't actually happens in the "client" side. After I call `create_connection()` in the "client" the `ws.connected` variable is still True, and when I do `ws.send()` the `on_message` method of the `websocketHandler` is still called and when it tries to make a response with `self.write_message()` it raises a `WebSocketClosedError`. And only then the "client" actually closes its side of the websocket, `ws.recv()` returns nothing and `ws.connected` turns to False after that.
Is there a way I can communicate to the client side (through handshake headers or something) that the websocket is meant to be closed earlier on its side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override `prepare()` and raise a `tornado.web.HTTPError`, instead of overriding `open()` and calling `self.close()`. This will reject the connection at the first opportunity and this will be reported on the client side as a part of `create_connection()` instead of on a later read.